# How to connect to SQL server database from jekyll?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

Can anybody give me some sample code showing how to connect to a SQL server database from jekyll's _config.yml?

Comment: Since Jekyll is a static site generator this seems like an odd thing to do. Perhaps you can explain why you want to do this?

Comment: It is possible to add database capabilities but not SQL server or MySQL  to your static sites.
 I am making use of firebase. Firebase by Google provides us many capabilities like storage, database , hosting and also access to serverless architecture using functions.

So coming to do point, all you need to do is register with http://firebase.google.com 
Then create an app and then in your JavaScript add required code in head tag

For more details,
You can visit my blog on this topic

https://xyzcoder.github.io/firebase/2019/03/17/firebase-real-time-database.html



Thanks,
Pavan

Answer (score 3):

Jekyll is a blog-aware, static site generator that does its generation based on the files contained in a very specific directory structure. Accessing an SQL database is not something that it can do, at least not out of the box. You could look at Jekyll plugins and see if there are any that meet your particular use case, but beyond that you might be better off looking at something more sophisticated like [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) or [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/).